# How to trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline when new branch is created and use the new branch name as a variable in the pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I use Azure DevOps as a for CI-CD for a Salesforce project to create a scratch org for feature development. How to trigger pipeline when a branch is created in GitHub?

How to pass a part of the new branch name a variable to the pipeline?
Ex: Branch Name - "Sample-GitHub-Branch", Variable to be passed in the pipeline - "Sample".

Answer (score 0):

On the base branch (i.e. **`main`**), set the CI trigger of the pipeline like as below.

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
```

Then, whenever you create a new branch (i.e. **`Sample-GitHub-Branch`**) based on the **`main`**, the pipeline will be triggered for the new branch.

In the triggered pipeline, you can use the [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) **`Build.SourceBranchName`** to get the branch name (**`Sample-GitHub-Branch`**). Then extract the specified sub-string from the value of it.

Comment: Thank you for the response it was very helpful. Is there any way to trigger the pipeline only when a new branch is created from master but not when code is committed to the newly created branch? Because after the branch is created from master, whenever a commit is done on the new branch the pipeline triggers and it should not.

Comment: @LikithJ, After creating a new branch, in the YAML file of this new branch, you need to update the trigger setting like as the following "**`trigger: none`**". With this setting, the pipeline will not be automatically triggered when you push new changes to the new branch. See "[**Disabling the CI trigger**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#disabling-the-ci-trigger)".